# How do I get the above and below the average in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have 3 GPAs I got the average by summing them and dividing by 3.
**Now, how can I get what is the GPA that above, below, and equal to the average??**

this is the code so far:

```
GPA1 = 4.28
GPA2 = 3.91
GPA3 = 3.64
sum = GPA1 + GPA2 + GPA3
average = sum / 3
print(average)
```

I tried If, Elif statements... it doesn't work with me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet of ifelse and exact reference value for above and below value

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution for this is:

```
GPA1 = 4.28
GPA2 = 3.91
GPA3 = 3.64
gpas = [GPA1, GPA2, GPA3] # pass everything into a list
average = sum(gpas)/len(gpas) # call it average so you don't override the inbuilt sum function
print(average)


below, above, equal = [], [], []
for gpa in gpas:
    if gpa < average:
        below.append(gpa)
    elif gpa == average:
        equal.append(gpa)
    else:
        above.append(gpa)
print("GPAs below:", below)
print("GPAs equal:", equal)
print("GPAs above:", above)
```

The key here is to group the GPAs together into something like a list. Then you can iterate over them in a forloop. Also, avoid using variable names reserved by Python such as `sum`, because then you cannot use them anymore to get, for example, the sum of a list (`sum(gpas)`).

Answer (score 0):

Save the values in a list and run a for loop over to check for the condition.

```
gpaList = [GPA1, GPA2, GPA3]
for gpa in gpaList:
    if gpa > average:
        #do stuff
        #for eg. print("Above average", gpa)
    else:
        #do stuff
        #for eg. print("Below or equal to average", gpa)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague I guess your asking for the process/algorithm

- make containers for over,under and equal_to
- iterate over the values

  - compare the value to the mean

    - put it in the correct container based on the comparison result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for I in [GPA1,GPA2,GPA3]:
     if I>average:
         Print ("above average" , I)
     elif I==average:
          Print ("equal to average" , I)
      else:
          Print (”below average" , I)
```